# Acumatica TestSDK_17_207_0029_18 Failure to generate wrappers

Tags: acumatica

I am following the documentation for Part1: General Ledger and Cash Management where you are instructed to run the Classgenerator.exe.

**Expected results:** Page Wrappers successfully generated

**Actual results:** System.AppDomainUnloadedException: The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

I have verified my ClassGenerator.exe.config to be correct.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SitePhysicalPath" value="E:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\960 Instances\AcumaticaIntegrations"/>
    <add key="GenResultPath" value="C:\SDK\ClassGenerator\Out"/>
    <add key="Username" value="admin@Company"/>
    <add key="Namespace" value="GeneratedWrappers.Acumatica"/>
    <add key="ClearOutput" value="true"/>
    <add key="FilenameFilter" value="CS100000, CS102000, CM202000, GL201500, CS202000, GL202500, GL102000, GL101000, GL201000"/>
    <!--<add key="PagesList" value="list.txt"/>
    <add key="PagesListAttribute" value="exclude"/>
    <add key="PagesListAttribute" value="include"/>
    <add key="PagesParameters" value="ParamsPP.txt"/>
    <add key="GenericInquiryParameters" value="ParamsGI.txt"/>-->
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Every time I try to run the class Generator exe I get this error.

```
    C:\Users\jonat\Downloads\TestSDK_17_207_0029_18\ClassGenerator>ClassGenerator.exe
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateInstanceInNewWorkerAppDomain(Type type, String appId, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(Type hostType, String virtualDir, String physicalDir)
   at ClassGenerator.ScreenExtractor.GetProxy() in E:\Bld\AC-TESTSDK2017R207-JOB1\tests\Selenium\ClassGenerator\ClassGenerator\ScreenExtractor.cs:line 64
   at ClassGenerator.ScreenExtractor..ctor(String virtualPath, String sitePhysicalPath, String genResultPath, String username, String namespace, String postfix, Boolean correctCTL01) in E:\Bld\AC-TESTSDK2017R207-JOB1\tests\Selenium\ClassGenerator\ClassGenerator\ScreenExtractor.cs:line 28
   at ClassGenerator.ClassGenerator.Run() in E:\Bld\AC-TESTSDK2017R207-JOB1\tests\Selenium\ClassGenerator\ClassGenerator\ClassGenerator.cs:line 177
   at ClassGenerator.Launcher.Main(String[] args) in E:\Bld\AC-TESTSDK2017R207-JOB1\tests\Selenium\ClassGenerator\ClassGenerator\Launcher.cs:line 11
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Hi Rob, I cleaned up the format a bit. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: How much RAM has your machine? Check it on case of overloading. Also try to install updates for .net framework and hotfixes for IIS.

Comment: I have 32GB RAM, but i'll try to update .net to see if that's the issue.I have the most recent version though